# Defining a class that has a field of the same class. Class with self references?

Tags: c#, class, self-reference

It seems weird that you can define a class that has a member field that is of that class.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person Spouse { get; set; }
}
```

Now if I call that class:

```
var jane = new Person();
var jim = new Person();
jane.Spouse = jim;
jim.Spouse.Spouse = jane;
```

The last line causes an error. But I'm having a bit of trouble imaging what what the jim.Spouse.Spouse call is doing. It should evaluate jim.spouse first which is null so it causes an error right? If I assert jim.Spouse = jane  first then it should work? But then I'm essentially saying jane.spouse = jane.

If a class has a field of the same type then what is it doing to the class? Is it just allowing two instances of the class to have a relationship?  The class  references itself so it's inheriting from itself? I'm kinda confused and also wondering if this is bad practice.

Comment: If the answer works, you should click the checkmark to indicate that.  Since you have not yet done so, please take the [Tour] to see some details on how SO works.  Accepted and upvoted answers help others find good answers

Answer (score 5):

You've asked several things here, but in general it's fine to have a reference to the same type (even the same instance) on an object.

```
public class Thing {
    private string name;

    public Thing(string name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Thing Other {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

var o = new Thing("Foo");
o.Other = o;
Debug.WriteLine(o.Other.Other.Other.Other.ToString()); // Could go on forever
```

1. You're correct in your assertion about the exception. It throws because `jim.Spouse` is a null reference, so you can't set a property on it.
2. If you set `jim.Spouse = jane;`, then you should be able to set a reference. In this case you would want to say `jim.Spouse.Spouse = jim;`, since `jim.Spouse` evaluates to `jane`.
3. Regarding the fields of the same type, it's no different to anything else. It's just a variable with a type that the class uses. It is not an uncommon pattern for a type to have a reference to something else of the same type. For example, an Employee class might have a reference to a Manager, who is also an Employee. Another common example is tree implementations, in a binary tree a Node will have a reference to a Left/Right Child node.